# synchronisation in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a problem with my javascript program

```
globID = oController.getGlobalId();
  console.log(globID);
//instructions using globID
```

---

```
oController.getGlobalId()
{

//instructions

console.log(ID);

return ID;
}
```

when i call the function, the value of undefined is asigned to globID. 
and in the log a have this order:
1- console.log(globID);
2- console.log(ID);

is there a solution to execute the function and then assign the real value to globID ?

thanks a lot.

Best Regards.

Comment: in the function, i have some instructions that bring the value of ID with an oData service, it works correctly

Comment: Shouldn't it be `oController.getGlobalId = function()`?

Comment: It's working fine for me. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/P2XtW/)

Comment: thanks tewathia, but it still not working for me
getGlobalId is function which is placed in the controller, ir brings the value of ID via odata service and then, in the view i will use this value so there is 2 different JS files

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are two different files. Just make sure the function is properly defined by the time it is called. The 'inner' console.log would print your `ID` value just as the `getGlobalId` function is called, before even returning the value that you're assigning to your `globId`

Comment: You mention that you're getting the global id via a service which leads me to think that your problem is not in any of the code you posted but rather in the commented out `//instructions` part. I strongly suspect that the API you're using is asynchronous.

Comment: ID doesn't even exists. So this is what should happen.

Comment: @RajeshPaul In his first comment he's mentioned that the ID value is defined in the instructions, in the function

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your `getGlobalId` method properly. It should look like:

```
oController.getGlobalId = function () {
    //instructions
    console.log('in function', ID);
    return ID;
}
```

Then

```
globID = oController.getGlobalId();
  console.log(globID);
```

would work properly(and give you the two console logs in the proper order)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/P2XtW/1/)

Comment: Hi,it isn't a definition problem of the function.
but i have a problem in the odata instructions

Comment: @user3134838 Could you create a fiddle to reproduce the problem? As it stands, there's nothing wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

i can't create a fiddle because the odata service must be execute in a specific environment, there is the code : 
in the view :

```
globID = oController.getGlobalId();

console.log('view',globID);

//instructions using globID
```

in the controller:

```
getGlobalId:function() {





oModel = this.getModel();



target =this.getSystemName();



oModel.read(/'SolutionManager(\'0050569b-0081-1ee1-9ff7-a45fec113fb6\')/TechnicalSystemsStatus',null, null, true, function(oData,oResponse){

for (var y = 0; y < number; y++) {




if ( oData.results[y].ID == target)





{

                globID = oData.results[y].GlobalID;

               console.log('controller',globID);


return globID;



}

//......
```

the console displays (with a small delays between the display of the two rows):

LOG: viewundefined

LOG: controller0050569b-0081-1ee1-9fb6-27bed6190dcf

i'm certain that the delay is caused by the odata call but i don't found a solution for that

thanks tewathia for your efforts

Comment: Looks like an async call issue...the callback function is only executed after the odata call is complete. But before that the rest of the `getGlobalId` function is executed, without returning anything, so your `globId` remains undefined

Comment: Just write `oController.getGlobalId();` instead of `globID = oController.getGlobalId();`, since you're already assigning `globID = oData.results[y].GlobalID;` inside the function. In the absence of the `var` keyword, `globID` would be a global variable

Comment: Thanks tewathia but it doesn't solve the problem :( 
because globID is a local variable which is declared within getGlobalID() function

Comment: Use `window.globId = oData.results[y].GlobalID;` then

Comment: i have again the async call issue
the same delay

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot 
it works now :)
you saved my life :)